# What is the difference in creating a system axes in a metadata with that of creating system axes in document in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, bi-temporal

I want to understand the difference of creating a system axes in a metadata with that of creating system axes in document in MarkLogic.

I have followed this link and I have executed as it instructs but I cannot understand the difference as nothing changes in the way it represents the files under the database.

System axes in a document - As per my understanding I thought it would take a field from the document and update that with the transaction time.
Can this be achieved anyway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/managing#id_59302

> Unlike when the system axes is stored in metadata, **you must include the system start and end elements or properties when they are stored in the temporal document**. They can either be null or include a timestamp, which will be reset by MarkLogic.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/managing#id_38470

> As described in [Bi-temporal Collections](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/managing#id_62701), the bi-temporal document being inserted or updated **must** specify valid start and end times **either in the document or in metadata**. When the system start and end times are stored in the document, they also must be included. These times must be `dateTime` values identified by elements that map to the range indexes that represent the valid start and end time period. **On insert, MarkLogic sets the system start time to the current time system time and the system end time to the farthest possible time (infinity).**
>
> If you have enabled LSQT, as described in [Last Stable Query Time (LSQT) and Application-controlled System Time](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/managing#id_75536), you can alternatively have your application call the [`temporal:statement-set-system-time`](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal:statement-set-system-time) function to specify a system start time along with your insert. The `dateTime` given must be later than the LSQT returned by the [`temporal:get-lsqt`](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal:get-lsqt) function.